# WCF DataService throws Exception that cannot be caught

Tags: c#, xamarin, wcf-data-services, xamarin.forms

In my *Xamarin Forms* app I use WCF Data Service update like this:

```
try
{
  SRef.MyEntities entities = new SRef.MyEntities(new Uri(App.BaseURL));
  DataServiceQuery query = (DataServiceQuery) entities.DataEntry.First();
  query.BeginExecute((result) =>
    {
      try
      {
        query.BeginExecute((result) =>
        {
          try
          {
            var actData = query.EndExecute(result).FirstOrDefault();
            if (actData != null)
            {
              actData.Info = "Info2";
              entities.UpdateObject(actData);
              entities.BeginSaveChanges((result2) =>
                {
                  try
                  {
                    entities.EndSaveChanges(result2);
                  }
                  catch (Exception ex2)
                  {
                    Alert("Error: " + ex2.Message);
                  }
                }, null);
            }
          }
          catch (Exception ex1)
          {
            Alert("Error: " + ex1.Message);
          }
    }, query);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Alert("Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

When it runs, I get the following exception *that can't be caught* and the **EndSaveChanges** doesn't run:

```
---- DEBUG ASSERTION FAILED ----
03-16 09:59:22.057 D: DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
[0:] ---- DEBUG ASSERTION FAILED ----
D: DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
D: DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
D: Searching for '__android_log_print'.
D: Probing '__android_log_print'.
D: Found as '__android_log_print'.
I: ---- DEBUG ASSERTION FAILED ----
[0:] 
---- Assert Short Message ----
I: ---- Assert Short Message ----
[0:] 
Expected DateTimeOffset to be a UTC value.
[0:] Expected DateTimeOffset to be a UTC value.
I: Expected DateTimeOffset to be a UTC value.
[0:] 
   at System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener.Fail(System.String message, System.String detailMessage)
I:    at System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener.Fail(System.String message, System.String detailMessage)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.Fail(System.String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener.Fail(System.String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceImpl.Fail(System.String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceImpl.Assert(Boolean condition, System.String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(Boolean condition, System.String message)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.PlatformHelper.ConvertDateTimeToStringInternal(DateTime dateTime)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.PlatformHelper.ConvertDateTimeToString(DateTime dateTime)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomConvert.ToString(DateTime dt)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.AtomValueUtils.TryConvertPrimitiveToString(System.Object value, System.String ByRef result)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.AtomValueUtils.ConvertPrimitiveToString(System.Object value)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.AtomValueUtils.WritePrimitiveValue(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer, System.Object value)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomPropertyAndValueSerializer.WritePrimitiveValue
I:    at System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.Fail(System.String message)
[0:]    at System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener.Fail(System.String message, System.String detailMessage)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.Fail(System.String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener.Fail(System.String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceImpl.Fail(System.String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceImpl.Assert(Boolean condition, System.String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(Boolean condition, System.String message)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.PlatformHelper.ConvertDateTimeToStringInternal(DateTime dateTime)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.PlatformHelper.ConvertDateTimeToString(DateTime dateTime)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomConvert.ToString(DateTime dt)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.AtomValueUtils.TryConvertPrimitiveToString(System.Object value, System.String ByRef result)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.AtomValueUtils.ConvertPrimitiveToString(System.Object value)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.AtomValueUtils.WritePrimitiveValue(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer, System.Object value)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomPropertyAndValueSerializer.WritePrimitiveValue(System.Object value, Microsoft.Data.OData.CollectionWithoutExpectedTypeValidator collectionValidator, IEdmTypeReference expectedTypeReference, Microsoft.Data.OData.SerializationTypeNameAnnotation typeNameAnnotation)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomPropertyAndValueSerializer.WriteProperty(Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataProperty property, IEdmStructuredType owningType, Boolean isTopLevel, Boolean isWritingCollection, System.Action beforePropertyAction, Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.EpmValueCache epmValueCache, Microsoft.Data.OData.Metadata.EpmSourcePathSegment epmParentSourcePathSegment, Microsoft.Data.OData.DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, Microsoft.Data.OData.ProjectedPropertiesAnnotation projectedProperties)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomPropertyAndValueSerializer.WriteProperties(IEdmStructuredType owningType, IEnumerable`1 cachedProperties, Boolean isWritingCollection, System.Action beforePropertiesAction, System.Action afterPropertiesAction, Microsoft.Data.OData.DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.EpmValueCache epmValueCache, Microsoft.Data.OData.Metadata.EpmSourcePathSegment epmSourcePathSegment, Microsoft.Data.OData.ProjectedPropertiesAnnotation projectedProperties)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomWriter.WriteEntryContent(Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataEntry entry, IEdmEntityType entryType, Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.EntryPropertiesValueCache propertiesValueCache, Microsoft.Data.OData.Metadata.EpmSourcePathSegment rootSourcePathSegment, Microsoft.Data.OData.ProjectedPropertiesAnnotation projectedProperties)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomWriter.EndEntry(Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.b__16()
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.InterceptException(System.Action action)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.WriteEndImplementation()
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.WriteEnd()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ODataWriterWrapper.WriteEnd(Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataEntry entry, System.Object entity)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.Serializer.WriteEntry(System.Data.Services.Client.EntityDescriptor entityDescriptor, IEnumerable`1 relatedLinks, System.Data.Services.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper requestMessage)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseSaveResult.CreateRequestData(System.Data.Services.Client.EntityDescriptor entityDescriptor, System.Data.Services.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper requestMessage)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseSaveResult.CreateChangeData(Int32 index, System.Data.Services.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper requestMessage)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.SaveResult.CreateNonBatchChangeData(Int32 index, System.Data.Services.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper requestMessage)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.SaveResult.BeginCreateNextChange()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.BeginSaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.BeginSaveChanges(System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state)
   at StefaniaXamarin.ViewModel.PaciensAdatokViewModel+c__DisplayClass4.b__1(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.HandleCompleted()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.HandleCompleted(System.Data.Services.Client.PerRequest pereq)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.PostInvokeAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.AsyncCallback callback)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.InvokeAsync(System.Data.Services.Client.AsyncAction asyncAction, System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 length, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ReadResponseStream(System.Data.Services.Client.AsyncStateBag asyncStateBag)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult+c__DisplayClass2.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.SimpleAsyncResult+c__AnonStorey0.m__0(System.Net.SimpleAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.SimpleAsyncResult.DoCallback_internal()
   at System.Net.WebAsyncResult.DoCallback()
   at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.ReadCallbackWrapper(IAsyncResult r)
(System.Object value, Microsoft.Data.OData.CollectionWithoutExpectedTypeValidator collectionValidator, IEdmTypeReference expectedTypeReference, Microsoft.Data.OData.SerializationTypeNameAnnotation typeNameAnnotation)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomPropertyAndValueSerializer.WriteProperty(Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataProperty property, IEdmStructuredType owningType, Boolean isTopLevel, Boolean isWritingCollection, System.Action beforePropertyAction, Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.EpmValueCache epmValueCache, Microsoft.Data.OData.Metadata.EpmSourcePathSegment epmParentSourcePathSegment, Microsoft.Data.OData.DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, Microsoft.Data.OData.ProjectedPropertiesAnnotation projectedProperties)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomPropertyAndValueSerializer.WriteProperties(IEdmStructuredType owningType, IEnumerable`1 cachedProperties, Boolean isWritingCollection, System.Action beforePropertiesAction, System.Action afterPropertiesAction, Microsoft.Data.OData.Dupl
I:    at System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener.Fail(System.String message)
icatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.EpmValueCache epmValueCache, Microsoft.Data.OData.Metadata.EpmSourcePathSegment epmSourcePathSegment, Microsoft.Data.OData.ProjectedPropertiesAnnotation projectedProperties)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomWriter.WriteEntryContent(Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataEntry entry, IEdmEntityType entryType, Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.EntryPropertiesValueCache propertiesValueCache, Microsoft.Data.OData.Metadata.EpmSourcePathSegment rootSourcePathSegment, Microsoft.Data.OData.ProjectedPropertiesAnnotation projectedProperties)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomWriter.EndEntry(Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.b__16()
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.InterceptException(System.Action action)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.WriteEndImplementation()
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.WriteEnd()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.OData
I:    at System.Diagnostics.TraceImpl.Fail(System.String message)
WriterWrapper.WriteEnd(Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataEntry entry, System.Object entity)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.Serializer.WriteEntry(System.Data.Services.Client.EntityDescriptor entityDescriptor, IEnumerable`1 relatedLinks, System.Data.Services.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper requestMessage)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseSaveResult.CreateRequestData(System.Data.Services.Client.EntityDescriptor entityDescriptor, System.Data.Services.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper requestMessage)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseSaveResult.CreateChangeData(Int32 index, System.Data.Services.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper requestMessage)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.SaveResult.CreateNonBatchChangeData(Int32 index, System.Data.Services.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper requestMessage)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.SaveResult.BeginCreateNextChange()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.BeginSaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state
I:    at System.Diagnostics.TraceImpl.Assert(Boolean condition, System.String message)
)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.BeginSaveChanges(System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state)
   at StefaniaXamarin.ViewModel.PaciensAdatokViewModel+c__DisplayClass4.b__1(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.HandleCompleted()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.HandleCompleted(System.Data.Services.Client.PerRequest pereq)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.PostInvokeAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.AsyncCallback callback)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.InvokeAsync(System.Data.Services.Client.AsyncAction asyncAction, System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 length, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ReadResponseStream(System.Data.Services.Client.AsyncStateBag asyncStateBag)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndRead(IAsyncResul
I:    at System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(Boolean condition, System.String message)
t asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult+c__DisplayClass2.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.SimpleAsyncResult+c__AnonStorey0.m__0(System.Net.SimpleAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.SimpleAsyncResult.DoCallback_internal()
   at System.Net.WebAsyncResult.DoCallback()
   at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.ReadCallbackWrapper(IAsyncResult r)
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.PlatformHelper.ConvertDateTimeToStringInternal(DateTime dateTime)
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.PlatformHelper.ConvertDateTimeToString(DateTime dateTime)
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomConvert.ToString(DateTime dt)
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.AtomValueUtils.TryConvertPrimitiveToString(System.Object value, System.String ByRef result)
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.AtomValueUtils.ConvertPrimitiveToString(System.Object value)
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.AtomValueUtils.WritePrimitiveValue(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer, System.Object value)
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomPropertyAndValueSerializer.WritePrimitiveValue(System.Object value, Microsoft.Data.OData.CollectionWithoutExpectedTypeValidator collectionValidator, IEdmTypeReference expectedTypeReference, Microsoft.Data.OData.SerializationTypeNameAnnotation typeNameAnnotation)
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomPropertyAndValueSerializer.WriteProperty(Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataProperty property, IEdmStructuredType owningType, Boolean isTopLevel, Boolean isWritingCollection, System.Action beforePropertyAction, Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.EpmValueCache epmValueCache, Microsoft.Data.OData.Metadata.EpmSourcePathSegment epmParentSourcePathSegment, Microsoft.Data.OData.DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, Microsoft.Data.OData.ProjectedPropertiesAnnotation projectedProperties)
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomPropertyAndValueSerializer.WriteProperties(IEdmStructuredType owningType, IEnumerable`1 cachedProperties, Boolean isWritingCollection, System.Action beforePropertiesAction, System.Action afterPropertiesAction, Microsoft.Data.OData.DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.EpmValueCache epmValueCache, Microsoft.Data.OData.Metadata.EpmSourcePathSegment epmSourcePathSegment, Microsoft.Data.OData.ProjectedPropertiesAnnotation projectedProperties)
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomWriter.WriteEntryContent(Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataEntry entry, IEdmEntityType entryType, Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.EntryPropertiesValueCache propertiesValueCache, Microsoft.Data.OData.Metadata.EpmSourcePathSegment rootSourcePathSegment, Microsoft.Data.OData.ProjectedPropertiesAnnotation projectedProperties)
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomWriter.EndEntry(Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataEntry entry)
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.b__16()
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.InterceptException(System.Action action)
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.WriteEndImplementation()
I:    at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.WriteEnd()
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.ODataWriterWrapper.WriteEnd(Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataEntry entry, System.Object entity)
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.Serializer.WriteEntry(System.Data.Services.Client.EntityDescriptor entityDescriptor, IEnumerable`1 relatedLinks, System.Data.Services.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper requestMessage)
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseSaveResult.CreateRequestData(System.Data.Services.Client.EntityDescriptor entityDescriptor, System.Data.Services.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper requestMessage)
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseSaveResult.CreateChangeData(Int32 index, System.Data.Services.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper requestMessage)
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.SaveResult.CreateNonBatchChangeData(Int32 index, System.Data.Services.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper requestMessage)
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.SaveResult.BeginCreateNextChange()
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.BeginSaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state)
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.BeginSaveChanges(System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state)
I:    at MyXamarinProject.ViewModel.MyViewModel+c__DisplayClass4.b__1(IAsyncResult result)
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.HandleCompleted()
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.HandleCompleted(System.Data.Services.Client.PerRequest pereq)
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.PostInvokeAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.AsyncCallback callback)
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.InvokeAsync(System.Data.Services.Client.AsyncAction asyncAction, System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 length, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state)
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ReadResponseStream(System.Data.Services.Client.AsyncStateBag asyncStateBag)
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
I:    at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult+c__DisplayClass2.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
I:    at System.Net.SimpleAsyncResult+c__AnonStorey0.m__0(System.Net.SimpleAsyncResult result)
I:    at System.Net.SimpleAsyncResult.DoCallback_internal()
I:    at System.Net.WebAsyncResult.DoCallback()
I:    at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.ReadCallbackWrapper(IAsyncResult r)
```

It never hits any catch.

What is causing this? Why can't the catch block catch the exception?

Answer (score 0):

It's not throwing an exception. It's failing an assertion using the [`Debug.Assert()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Coincidentally, `Debug.Assert()` displays its' output in a MessageBox, which you are potentially mistaking for your `Alert()` method.

Relevant area of the error message:

```
I: ---- DEBUG ASSERTION FAILED ----
[0:] 
---- Assert Short Message ----
I: ---- Assert Short Message ----
[0:] 
Expected DateTimeOffset to be a UTC value.
[0:] Expected DateTimeOffset to be a UTC value.
I: Expected DateTimeOffset to be a UTC value.
[0:]  at System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener.Fail(System.String message, System.String detailMessage)
I:    at System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener.Fail(System.String message, System.String detailMessage)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.Fail(System.String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener.Fail(System.String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceImpl.Fail(System.String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceImpl.Assert(Boolean condition, System.String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(Boolean condition, System.String message)
```

Comment: If it is not an exception then why the EndSaveChanges never runs?

Comment: @Nestor I couldn't tell you. I'm not familiar with the Microsoft OData libraries. If it does throw an exception, it's catching it. You might try stepping into the server side implementation of `SaveChanges()`.